# Nginx Proxy Manager forward to vaultwarden in https throw an error 502

Tags: port-forwarding, nginx, https, reverse-proxy

On my QNAP TS-673A (192.168.0.228), i have installed the two followings docker images :

1. Vaultwarden (192.168.0.227)
2. Nginx Proxy Manager (NPM) with his intertace on NAT

On my box like i have the ports 443 and 80 already used by others services i have opened the followings ports :

•   16897 redirect to the port 35443 on NPM
•   16898 redirect to the port 35080 on NPM

On Nginx Proxy Manager, i have set up the domain https://pass.mondomaine.com

[image]

When i go on https://pass.mondomaine.com:16897/#/login, it throw an error 502 Bad Gateway

Why it's doesn't work ?